# Send consolidated email as reminder with fixed interval

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have SharePoint document library with UAT date and Assign to , i want to send an email after every 80 days to Assign to user ,i am able to do this but now i want to send a consolidated email to Assign user with all  item  which is Assign to him and UAT date is after 80 days ,

Currently it send email for each item separate , but i want it in consolidated .

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the list items assigned to particular users using the camel query and CSOM PowerShell script, then configure that PowerShell script in windows task schedular.

Refer to the below sample PowerShell script to send email from SharePoint online:

```
#variables region.
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
$spUserName="yourSharePointonlineaccount@yourtenantdomain.com"
$BCCUserName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$ccUserName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$toUserName = "Global-sharepoint@globalsharepoint.onmicrosoft.com"
$emailBody = "Test email from SharePoint online CSOM PowerShell script." 
$password = "YourPassword"
#variables region end.
$securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
  
#Setup the Context
try
{
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($spUserName, $securePassword)  
$clientCSOMEMailProperties=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.EmailProperties        
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.BCC= [Collections.Generic.List[String]]@($BCCUserName) 
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.CC=[Collections.Generic.List[String]]@($CCUserName) 
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.To=[Collections.Generic.List[String]]@($ToUserName) 
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.From=$spUserName 
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.Body=$emailBody
$clientCSOMEMailProperties.Subject="Test email from SharePoint online CSOM PowerShell script." 
$csomUtility=[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility]::SendEmail($ctx, $clientCSOMEMailProperties)        
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
$ctx.Dispose() 
}
catch 
{
  
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in sending email from CSOM SharePoint online";
    Write-Host $errorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
    Write-Log $errorMessage 
}         
Write-Host "##########################################################"
Write-Host "Test email from SharePoint online CSOM PowerShell script." -ForegroundColor Green 
Write-Host "##########################################################"
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online Automation – O365 – Send email from SharePoint online Using CSOM PowerShell script](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/send-email-from-sharepoint-online-using-csom-powershell/)

Comment: Thank you for the response but is there any way to get in designer

Comment: PowerShell script task schedular is recommended one approach - in the designer workflow, you might add "Pause Until Date" action - the downfall of that approach is the first time you need trigger the workflow manually and it takes unwanted resources as this will be paused for 80 days in your scenario.

Comment: Reminder is working fine SharePoint designer I am just unable to consolidate them as one email for each users